# How to make a line follow mouse event arctanget with class javascript

Tags: javascript, class, canvas

Hi every one I'm trying to make a line follow the mouse move event. I can do this with the ctx.save and restore but i don't know how to do if i want use class and draw other object.  In fact whit using save and restore It Work but if i want to have  the same result whit class i dont know how to do many thanks

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
        height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
        arrowX = width / 2,
        arrowY = height / 2,
        dx, dy,
        angle = 0,
        a = 0;

    render();

    function render() {
        arrowX = width / 2 + Math.cos(a) * height * .4;
        arrowY = height / 2 + Math.sin(a) * height * .4;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        context.save();
        context.translate(arrowX, arrowY);
        context.rotate(angle);

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(20, 0);
        context.lineTo(-20, 0);
        context.moveTo(20, 0);
        context.lineTo(10, -10);
        context.moveTo(20, 0);
        context.lineTo(10, 10);
        context.stroke();

        context.restore();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        dx = event.clientX - arrowX;
        dy = event.clientY - arrowY;
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    });


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <Canvas id="canvas"></Canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If i want use class i start like thaïs on  the following code

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var arrowX = width / 2;
        var arrowY = height -20;
        var dx; 
    var dy;
        var angle = 0;

    
     class Player{
        constructor(x,y,radius,color)
        {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.radius=radius;
        this.color=color;
        }

        draw(){
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2,false );
            c.fillStyle=this.color;
            c.fill();
        }
    }

    class Shooter{
        constructor(x,y,xEnd,yEnd,color){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            this.xEnd=xEnd;
            this.yEnd=yEnd;
            this.color=color;
            
        }
        draw(){
        c.beginPath();
        
            c.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
            c.lineTo(this.xEnd, this.yEnd);
        c.strokeStyle=this.color;
            c.stroke();
        }

      

    }

   // const player= new Player(arrowX,arrowY,20,'white');
    const shooter= new Shooter(arrowX,500,arrowX,arrowY,'white');

    let animationId;
    
    function animate(){
    animationId=requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.fillStyle='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    //player.draw();
    shooter.draw();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <Canvas id="canvas"></Canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer two methods for this. The first is to simply have the end of the vector the same coordinates as the mouse position. This will change the magnitude of the vector of course.

This method does not rotate or translate the context.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
var height = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()

let mouse = {x: 0, y: 0}

class Shooter {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xEnd = mouse.x;
    this.yEnd = mouse.y;
    this.color = color;
  }
  draw() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    c.lineTo(this.xEnd, this.yEnd);
    c.strokeStyle = this.color;
    c.stroke();
  }
  update() {
    this.xEnd = mouse.x;
    this.yEnd = mouse.y;
  }
}

const shooter = new Shooter(width/2, height/2, "white");

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.x;
        mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.y;
    });

function animate() {
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //player.draw();
  shooter.draw();
  shooter.update();
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <Canvas id="canvas"></Canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The second method draws the start point at (0, 0) but then you can use translate to position it where ever you want. This also rotates the context but allows you to keeps the magnitude the same.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
var height = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()

let mouse = {x: 0, y: 0}

class Shooter {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.xEnd = this.x + 50;
    this.yEnd = this.y;
    this.translate = {x: x, y: y}
    this.color = color;
    this.angle = 0;
  }
  draw() {
     this.angle = Math.atan2(mouse.y - this.translate.y, mouse.x - this.translate.x)
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.translate.x, this.translate.y);
    c.rotate(this.angle);
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    c.lineTo(this.xEnd, this.yEnd);
    c.strokeStyle = this.color;
    c.stroke();
    c.restore()
  }
  update() {
    
  }
}

const shooter = new Shooter(width/2, height/2, "white");

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.x;
        mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.y;
    });

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //player.draw();
  shooter.draw();
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <Canvas id="canvas"></Canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: many many thank you second method should be perfect form me

Comment: Awesome. Be sure to hit answer if it helped you. Thanks.